# How can I execute cat command using execvp or other kinds of exec functions in programming C

Tags: c, unix, exec, execvp

I have a problem which needs to be solved. I have a string array like :
`argv[]={"cat","file1.txt","file2.txt"}`,then I need to use execvp to execute the `execvp(argv[0],argv)`,but I feel why it doesn't work out in my program. I am not sure whether I can use execvp() functions like this, can someone tell me how to use execvp() or other kinds of exec() functions to run cat command in UNIX or Linus system(using programming C)?

Comment: Use the `man` command in your terminal. For example, run `man execvp` for a list of related `exec` functions.

Answer (score 3):

The array has to end with `0`:

```
char *argv[] = {"cat", "file1.txt", "file2.txt", 0};
```

That's how `execvp` knows where the end of the arguments is, since C doesn't pass the length of an array to functions.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an example. Think outside the box. You have access to Linux I take it. Run the following command and review the first line returned in the strace.

```
strace cat $file1, $file2
```

Customize your example to work from as you see fit. Now you should see the results on line 1 as:

```
execve("/usr/bin/cat", ["cat", "file1.txt,", "file2.txt"], 0x7fff2c4e7a70 /* 56 vars */) = 0
```

Notice the end of this line = 0 That is because you want to set the env to null in order to end the arguments on the syscall.

Now you can play with this in nasm and make sure that your code is working correctly.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35677511)